# Google Sheets conditional formatting with formula

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting

Here is the link to my google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1toBfSTFwIzlUOVZrWWjmhIOZizXuiJ091dYN70kZHcA/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to create conditional formatting based on a range of dates which does not seem to be working.

This is my formula:

```
=isnumber(vlookup(C12,$K$60:$K$71,1,0))
```

I used `=isnumber` because of the date issue.  The problem is that only the first cell of the cells selected to be conditionally formatted is changing color which I know is incorrect because the first cell does not even have a date number.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Google Sheets conditional formatting with formula]

Comment: I see that you are getting downvoted rapidly (not by me). That is likely for several reasons. First, the volunteer contributors here can't do much with an image. We'd need a link to see the spreadsheet (or a copy of it) with editor access to test anything. Second, it is highly unlikely on a volunteer-run forum such as this that people will take the time to watch a video. (The guidelines here ask that all pertinent information to understand the problem be contained within the post itself.) If you share a link and report back, I'll have a look.

Comment: At a glance, however, you can try locking your VLOOKUP references: `$K$60:$K$71`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I added the link to my Google Sheet to see if they can fix it!  I may need to unlock the sheet tho, right?

Comment: @ErikTyler I added the link to my spreadsheet however I don't think I will get much response because I have been voted down... will you help me? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1toBfSTFwIzlUOVZrWWjmhIOZizXuiJ091dYN70kZHcA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(C11, FILTER($K$60:$K$71, $K$60:$K$71<>""), 1, )*(ISNUMBER(C11))
```

or even:

```
=VLOOKUP(C11, $K$60:$K$71, 1, )*(ISNUMBER(C11))
```